# How to get list of tabs from Salesforce Org using Java?

Tags: java, salesforce, metadata

Is there a way to get the list of tabs from a Salesforce Org? I have tried using Metadata wsdl file and created a jar using force-wsc.jar. But I'm not able to retrieve the list of tabs. Please help or provide some pointers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For getting information about Salesforce tabs you can use SOAP API method [describeTabs()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describetabs.htm). Here is an example of using for Java:

```
public void describeTabsSample() {
  try {
    // Describe tabs
    DescribeTabSetResult[] dtsrs = connection.describeTabs();
    System.out.println("There are " + dtsrs.length + 
        " tab sets defined.");

    // For each tab set describe result, get some properties 
    for (int i = 0; i < dtsrs.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Tab Set " + (i + 1) + ":");
      DescribeTabSetResult dtsr = dtsrs[i];
      System.out.println("Label: " + dtsr.getLabel());
      System.out.println("\tLogo URL: " + dtsr.getLogoUrl());
      System.out.println("\tTab selected: " + 
          dtsr.isSelected());

      // Describe the tabs for the tab set
      DescribeTab[] tabs = dtsr.getTabs();
      System.out.println("\tTabs defined: " + tabs.length);

      // Iterate through the returned tabs
      for (int j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++) {
        DescribeTab tab = tabs[j];
        System.out.println("\tTab " + (j + 1) + ":");
        System.out.println("\t\tName: " + 
            tab.getSobjectName());
        System.out.println("\t\tLabel: " + tab.getLabel());
        System.out.println("\t\tURL: " + tab.getUrl());
        DescribeColor[] tabColors = tab.getColors();
        // Iterate through tab colors as needed
        DescribeIcon[] tabIcons = tab.getIcons();
        // Iterate through tab icons as needed
      }
    }
  } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
    ce.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```